# Can we embed adobe air sdk or jar file within apk file

Tags: android, flash-cs6

I Created an application in adobe flash CS6, and compile as .apk file, when i run on my device it demand to download adobe air for that application, my question is , is there any method to embed adobe air sdk/jar file within apk file.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Pro* CS-6----

Yeah, you have to follow some steps to embed Adobe AIR into your app for android device.

1.publish Setting (or ctrl+shift_F12)

2.click on Wrench icon [(Label)Target]

3.click on deployment Tag

you will see  AIR Runtime option has two radio button click on 
**"Embed AIR runtime with application"**

***But remember that- if Adobe AIR already installed on your device it causes an Error***